# Can I merge only non-conflicting changes in Git?

Tags: git, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

How can I simply (e.g. in one command?) merge in Git, keeping the state of conflicting files as in the current branch and without specifying each file individually as in theirs/ours options?

```
git checkout master
git merge stable --some-option-to-keep-files-?
```

Answer (score 5):

The merge strategy has an "ours" option which is what you want

```
git merge -s recursive -X ours remote/branch
```

As the manpage stresses out, this is NOT git merge -s ours.

Comment: isn't it `-s recursive -X ours`, or just `-X ours` as `recursive` is the default strategy?

Comment: I did "ours" erroneously. Is there a way to override "ours" and do "theirs" if the result of merging was pushed to Github?

Comment: Depends if people already pulled from that repository. If not, you can always reset --hard to the pre-merged state, redo the merge and force-push. If they did, it is a bit more tricky. You could reset to the pre-merged state using git merge -s theirs sha1_of_pre_merge_commit and then redo the merge I guess ... but that will look messy